# C# Type name unknown but declared

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes. The first one:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 private Infos _info;

 public Form1()
 {
  _info = new Infos();
  _info.NewData += new Infos.NewEventHandler(Evt);
 }
}
```

And this class:

```cs
public class Infos
{
 public delegate NewEventHandler(object sender, GetOut e);
 public event NewEventHandler NewData;
}
```

When I launch it, i got error message:

> Type name "NewEventHandler" does not exist in type "Infos".

So if you know why? Thanks you for help!

Comment: You didn't define a return type for your `NewEventHandler` delegate.

Comment: You might want to use the generic `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` instead of creating your own delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the return type for `NewEventHandler`, which is a syntax error.

If the event handler shouldn't return anything, add `void`:

```
public class Infos
{
 public delegate void NewEventHandler(object sender, GetOut e);
 public event NewEventHandler NewData;
}
```

EDIT: for a self-contained example that compiles and runs:

```
using System;

public class GetOut
{
}

public class Infos
{
    public delegate void NewEventHandler(object sender, GetOut g);
    public event NewEventHandler NewData;
}

public class Form1
{
    private Infos _info;

    public Form1()
    {
        _info = new Infos();
        _info.NewData += Func;
    }
    void Func(object sender, GetOut g)
    {

    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you but i have the same error message after this correction.